# Binding a WPF Data Grid with a datatable along with its parent class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a class that contains a datatable in it. I want to bind a WPF data grid containing six columns where first four columns will be binded with the properties of the parent class and last two columns will be binded
with the values in the columns of the datatable in it.

First four columns in data grid are pretty straight forward. I am confused about binding the values from datatable.

It will be somewhat like this

```
   //Code Behind

public class ParentClass()

{

public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
public string PropertyFour { get; set; }    
public DataTable Data { get; set; }

public class()
{
    Data.columns.add("ColumnOne");
    Data.columns.add("ColumnTwo");
    
    DataRow objRow = Data.newRow();
    objRow["ColumnOne"] = "ColumnOne";
    objRow["ColumnTwo"] = "ColumnTwo";
    
    Data.Rows.add(objRow);
}
```

Here comes the XAML code

```html
//XAML


<DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PropertyOne}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PropertyTwo}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Third" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PropertyThree}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fourth" Width="150" Binding="{Binding PropertyFour}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fifth" Width="150" Binding="{Binding ColumnOne}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sixth" Width="150">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtTest" text="{Binding ColumnTwo}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add two more properties and assign the value to those and bind them

```
public class ParentClass()
{
   public string PropertyOne { get; set; } 
   public string PropertyTwo { get; set; }
   public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
   public string PropertyFour { get; set; }     
   public string ColumnOne { get; set; }
   public string ColumnTwo{ get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass()
{
   DataTable Data = new DataTable();

   Data.columns.Add("ColumnOne");
   Data.columns.Add("ColumnTwo");
   Data.columns.Add("PropertyOne");
   ...
   Data.columns.Add("PropertyFour");

   DataRow objRow = Data.NewRow();

   objRow["PropertyOne"] = parentClass.PropertyOne;
    ...

   objRow["PropertyFour"] = parentClass.PropertyFour ;
   objRow["ColumnOne"] = "ColumnOne";
   objRow["ColumnTwo"] = "ColumnTwo";
   Data.Rows.Add(objRow);


    
}
//bind the Data to the grid
```

Or

```
public class OtherClass()
{
  //Read data from the database and assign them to the instance of the parent class and add them to the list you want to bind. 
   var parentClass = new ParentClass();
   //assign properties.
   //read the row from the database
   //assign the properties from the database.
   //add them to the list to bind 
   
}
```

What are you trying to achieve can work but is not at all recommended. use either of the two ways.

Comment: That's a plausible workaround but i was wondering if there is way to make a parent-child hierarchy in WPF ??

Comment: Other what is to make the whole thing into DataRows

Comment: Is it possible to use "DataGrid.InitializingNewItem" event of the grid. I hope it work like "DataBound" event of ASP.NET web application.

Once the New Item is created, get the new item in this event, extract the datatable inside and manually assign the values to two controls.

Workable ??

Comment: I have update the code hope it helps